# Непонятная граница в FireFox на кнопке

Tags: html, css, javascript

Непонятная граница в FireFox на кнопке. В начале все ок, когда я меняю ей стиль после click на ней появляется непонятная точечная граница[image]

Comment: А чего? Довольно красиво получается. Нестандартно, можно сказать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
outline: none;
```

http://htmlbook.ru/css/outline

Comment: там стоит, все равно не помогает