# Как изменить цвет рамки нажатой button

Tags: html, css

[image: Цвет рамки синий]

Как поменять синий цвет рамки уже нажатого `input type = 'button'` на какой-нибудь другой?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Непонятная граница в FireFox на кнопке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/180292/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%b2-firefox-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже, что это у вас :focus на этой кнопке. Попробуйте ей дать outline. Ну или меняйте его по тому же :focus.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить класс active при нажатии на кнопку и ему дать рамку какую надо...! Зависит от того что вам конкретно нужно, что бы она всегда такой была до следующего нажатия или просто на фокус...?

Comment: Когда использую focus, рамка появляется вокруг фокуса. Решил свою проблему с помощью `outline: none`.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно для неё задать псевдоклассы `:focus`, `:active` и применить `outline: none;`.

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

button:focus,
button:active {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```